# create failed bucket cannot have acls set with object ownership bucketownerenforced setting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to set up nimble studio(I use it and delete to reduce charges) but since yesterday, I have been getting the error "create failed bucket cannot have acls set with object ownership bucketownerenforced setting" I have made my bucket access public and changed ownership to object writer but am still getting the same error can someone help.

Setting up nimble studio.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is a new S3 bucket and [hence](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html):

> Starting in April 2023, Amazon S3 will change the default settings for S3 Block Public Access and Object Ownership (ACLs disabled) for all new S3 buckets. For new buckets created after this update, all S3 Block Public Access settings will be enabled, and S3 access control lists (ACLs) will be disabled.

Read the documentation about [Object Ownership](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html). Review the relevant S3 bucket settings. If you want/need to use ACLs then you will have to disable Object Ownership on the bucket.

Comment: This helped very much, i found a solution for the JS sdk (kinda) here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76130737/error-bucket-cannot-have-acls-set-with-objectownerships-bucketownerenforced