# Error: "Bucket cannot have ACLs set with ObjectOwnership's BucketOwnerEnforced" on creating bucket using aws js sdk client s3

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I tried to create a public-read ACL bucket using the AWS JavaScript SDK client for S3's `CreateBucketCommand`. It was working fine last week, but after recent AWS changes, I started receiving the following error message: 'Bucket cannot have ACLs set with ObjectOwnership's BucketOwnerEnforced'.

Here is the code I used to create the public bucket:

```
const command = new CreateBucketCommand({
  ACL: 'public-read',
  Bucket: bucket,
})
await this.S3Client.send(command)
```

What changes should I make to the code to create a public-read bucket using `CreateBucketCommand` that is compatible with the latest AWS changes?

Comment: See [PutBucketOwnershipControlsCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/classes/putbucketownershipcontrolscommand.html).

Comment: Adding ownership can be done using the flag **ObjectOwnership** in **CreateBucketCommand**

Comment: You may find this answer also helpful as it talks about the new changes and how to use ObjectOwnership to disable or enable ACLs to control ownership of objects: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76335671/12326605

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couldn't find a solution that can create a public bucket just by modifying `CreateBucketCommand`. So to achieve the result, I needed to add `ObjectOwnership: 'BucketOwnerPreferred'` (which is optional and the default value for ObjectOwnership is BucketOwnerPreferred ) flag to `CreateBucketCommand` and put public access to that bucket using `PutPublicAccessBlockCommand`.

Here is the code modified to achieve the same.

```
  async createBucket(options) {
    const { bucket } = options
    const command = new CreateBucketCommand({
      Bucket: bucket,
      ObjectOwnership: 'BucketOwnerPreferred',
      // ACL: 'public-read',
    })
    await this.S3Client.send(command)

    await this.putPublicAccess(options)

    return { bucket }
  }

  async putPublicAccess(options) {
    const { bucket } = options
    const input = {
      Bucket: bucket,
      PublicAccessBlockConfiguration: {
        BlockPublicAcls: false,
        IgnorePublicAcls: false,
        BlockPublicPolicy: false,
        RestrictPublicBuckets: false,
      },
    }
    const command = new PutPublicAccessBlockCommand(input)
    await this.S3Client.send(command)
    return { bucket }
  }
```