# AWS S3: InvalidBucketAclWithObjectOwnershipBucket cannot have ACLs set with ObjectOwnership's BucketOwnerEnforcedACL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Since a few years, I have had a PHP Script that allows me to generate Buckets and upload some public images to it.
now my Method starts to spit out the same Error again and again:
`InvalidBucketAclWithObjectOwnership`
for now, it was:

```
$s3 = new \Aws\S3\S3Client($awsConf);
$s3->createBucket(['ACL' => $acl,'Bucket' => $bucket_name]);
```

So I found a possible solution to add another option:

```
'ObjectOwnership' => 'BucketOwnerForced',
```

But nothing changed for me. Do you have any ideas about what I have to add to the API call?

EDIT:

FULL ERROR:

> Error executing "CreateBucket" on "https://rhmpicsneu1.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `PUT https://rhmpicsneu1.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
>
> `InvalidBucketAclWithObjectOwnership`Bucket cannot hav (truncated...)
> InvalidBucketAclWithObjectOwnership (client): Bucket cannot have ACLs set with ObjectOwnership's BucketOwnerEnforced setting - 
> `InvalidBucketAclWithObjectOwnership`Bucket cannot have ACLs set with ObjectOwnership's BucketOwnerEnforced settingXXE0VAW96NHT89XC2VCYWewOiAFgS1iXhZUW0ku8pAgQSDkOQAcOVEn0wTwV0HwE9IkUQhxeRdhFBsoEmaXad5EFKrbL586AY1Q+ww==

Comment: this is the whole code except the definition of $awConf where is only the credentials and region is stored.  Everything else is the aws-sdk-php/ - Aws\S3\S3Client its all within the same aws account no cross account action

Comment: full error msg is added

Comment: $acl only contains a string: $acl = "public-read"

Comment: still same error msg

Answer (score 2):

From [Amazon S3 Security Changes Are Coming in April of 2023](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/heads-up-amazon-s3-security-changes-are-coming-in-april-of-2023/)

> Starting in April of 2023, all newly created buckets in the Region
> will by default have **S3 Block Public Access** enabled and **access
> control lists (ACLs)** disabled. Both of these options are already
> console defaults and have long been recommended as best practices. The
> options will become the default for buckets that are created using the
> *S3 API*, *S3 CLI*, the *AWS SDKs*, or *AWS CloudFormation templates*.
>
> **ACLs Disabled** – **The Bucket owner enforced** setting will be enabled for newly created buckets, making bucket ACLs and object ACLs
> ineffective, and ensuring that the bucket owner is the object owner no
> matter who uploads the object. **If you want to enable ACLs for a
> bucket, you can set the `ObjectOwnership` parameter to `ObjectWriter`
> in your `CreateBucket` request or you can call
> `DeleteBucketOwnershipControls` after you create the bucket**. You will
> need `s3:PutBucketOwnershipControls` permission in order to use the
> parameter or to call the function;

So to have a Bucket with ACL enabled with `public-read`, first, you need to create the bucket with `'ObjectOwnership' => 'ObjectWriter'` or `'ObjectOwnership' => 'BucketOwnerPreferred'`. And then Disable **Block all public access** so Bucket ACL can be updated to `public-read` in the next step. Please check the below screenshot of the bucket created.

With PHP SDK, you can do like so:-

```php
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

//Create an S3Client
$s3client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'ap-south-1'
]);

$bucket_name = "test-sdk-arpit";
try {
    //Create Bucket with ObjectOwnership as ObjectWriter which make ACL as enabled.
    $s3client->createBucket([
        'Bucket' => $bucket_name,
        'ObjectOwnership' => 'ObjectWriter'
    ]);
    echo "Created bucket named: $bucket_name \n";
    
    
    //Disable Block all public access so we can update ACL to public-read else it will give access denied error.
    $result = $s3client->putPublicAccessBlock([
        'Bucket' => $bucket_name, // REQUIRED
        'PublicAccessBlockConfiguration' => [ // REQUIRED
            'BlockPublicAcls' => false
        ],
    ]);
    echo "Disable Block all public access for bucket:$bucket_name\n";
    
    //Update Bucket ACL for public-read access.
    $result = $s3client->putBucketAcl([
        'ACL' => 'public-read',
        'Bucket' => $bucket_name, // REQUIRED
    ]);
    echo "Updated ACL to public read for bucket:$bucket_name make \n";
    
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    echo "Failed to create/update bucket $bucket_name with error: " . $exception->getMessage();
    exit("Please fix error with bucket creation before continuing.");
}
```

[**ObjectOwnership**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#createbucket) Object Ownership has three settings that you can use to control ownership of objects uploaded to your bucket and to disable or enable ACLs:-

- `ObjectWriter` - The uploading account will own the object if the object is uploaded with the bucket-owner-full-control canned ACL.
  (The object writer remains the object owner. ACLs are still used for
  access control. ie ***ACLs enabled***)
- `BucketOwnerEnforced` - Access control lists (ACLs) are disabled and no
  longer affect permissions. The bucket owner automatically owns and
  has full control over every object in the bucket. The bucket only
  accepts PUT requests that don't specify an ACL or bucket owner full
  control ACLs, such as the bucket-owner-full-control canned ACL or an
  equivalent form of this ACL expressed in the XML format. ie. ***(ACLs disabled)***
- `BucketOwnerPreferred` - Objects uploaded to the bucket change
  ownership to the bucket owner if the objects are uploaded with the
  `bucket-owner-full-control` canned ACL. ie. ***(ACLs enabled)***
  [image]

Useful Resources:-

- [Heads-Up: Amazon S3 Security Changes Are Coming in April of 2023](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/heads-up-amazon-s3-security-changes-are-coming-in-april-of-2023/)
- [New – Simplify Access Management for Data Stored in Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-simplify-access-management-for-data-stored-in-amazon-s3/)
- [Controlling ownership of objects and disabling ACLs for your bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html)
- [AWS SDK - CreateBucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#createbucket)