# Error creating S3 bucket: InvalidBucketAclWithObjectOwnership

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws

I'm having trouble with this terraform file. This file is create s3 bucket. but unfortunately when i enter command "docker-compose run --rm terraform apply" I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Error creating S3 bucket: InvalidBucketAclWithObjectOwnership: Bucket cannot have ACLs set with ObjectOwnership's BucketOwnerEnforced setting
        status code: 400, request id: C2PJ5X9D5VZGHTRF, host id: TulblRSmwa9BqK/LloIhEjqQEZV/3u0qR5XjfL0ccQ2UbjGIw0HI1v/w4buH4oFTCI1/nVn2e2A=

  on main.tf line 19, in resource "aws_s3_bucket" "website":
  19: resource "aws_s3_bucket" "website" {
```

This is my main.tf file

```
variable "domain_name" {
  description = "The name of the domain for our website."
  default = "travelnirmalcalifornia.org"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "bucket_policy" {
  statement {
    sid = "PublicReadGetObject"
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [ "s3:GetObject" ]
    principals {
      type = "*"
      identifiers = [ "*" ]
    }
    resources = [ "arn:aws:s3:::${var.domain_name}" ]
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "website" {
  
  bucket = var.domain_name          // The name of the bucket.
  acl    = "public-read"      
  
        
  
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.bucket_policy.json
  website {
    index_document = "index.htm"   // The root of the website.
    error_document = "error.htm"   // The page to show when people hit invalid pages.
  }
}

output "website_bucket_url" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket.website.website_endpoint
}
```

I tried removing acl in my AWS account s3. but error i getting. [This is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AWUE.png)

Comment: To create a Bucket with ACL enabled with `public-read`, first, you need to create the bucket with `'ObjectOwnership' => 'ObjectWriter'` or `'ObjectOwnership' => 'BucketOwnerPreferred'`. And then Disable Block all public access so Bucket ACL can be updated to public-read. Please check this detail answer:- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76335671/12326605